# How to fix yacc: "2 shift/reduce conflicts" error?

Tags: yacc

I started to programming a few days ago in yacc / flex and i don't know why I can't do recursive call only in line 31 (s: SKIP { System.out.println("txt: "+$1); } s). The recursive call enables me to keep on digit free text without using parenthesis.. What I'm doing wrong?

```
%{
  import java.io.*;
%}

%token OPEN_PAREN;
%token CLOSE_PAREN;
%token <sval> SKIP;

%start s

%%

parens  : OPEN_PAREN s CLOSE_PAREN
        | OPEN_PAREN CLOSE_PAREN

exp     : parens

exps    : exp SKIP { System.out.println("S: "+$2); }
        | exp

s       : SKIP { System.out.println("txt: "+$1); } s
        | exps
        | s exps

%%

void yyerror(String s)
{
 System.out.println("err:"+s);
 System.out.println("   :"+yylval.sval);
}

static Yylex lexer;
int yylex()
{
 try {
  return lexer.yylex();
 }
 catch (IOException e) {
  System.err.println("IO error :"+e);
  return -1;
 }
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
 System.out.println("[Quit with CTRL-D]");
 Parser par = new Parser();
 lexer = new Yylex(new InputStreamReader(System.in), par);
 par.yyparse();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one shift/reduce conflict in that excerpt, which is the result of the ambiguous recursiveness in `s`. Since it has nothing to do with the mid-rule action, it can be simplified to the following:

```
s: BEFORE s
 | AFTER
 | s AFTER
```

which is a grammar for `BEFORE* AFTER+`. (The fact that `AFTER` in your grammar is actually a non-terminal doesn't change anything either.)

This is ambiguous because the order of applying the first and last productions is not constrained by the grammar. Even in the simple input

```
BEFORE AFTER AFTER
```

there are two different parses:

```
      s                             s
   /     \                       /    \
  /       \                     /      \
BEFORE     s                   s      AFTER
  |      /   \               /   \      |
  |    AFTER   s         BEFORE   s     |
  |      |     |            |     |     |
BEFORE AFTER AFTER       BEFORE AFTER AFTER
```

Possibly it doesn't matter to you which of these parses is applied (although actually it does, because it affects the order of execution of the actions). But it matters to bison/yacc, which cannot know whether the order is unimportant or not.

To solve the conflict, we need to specify an order. There are two possibilities:

1. Postfix before prefix. This is the usual order applied in programming languages, where postfix operators (like array subscripting) bind more tightly than prefix operators (like unary minus), so that `-a[1]` is the same as `-(a[1])` rather than `(-a)[1]`. In that case the grammar would look like this:

   ```
   s: t
    | BEFORE s
   t: AFTER
    | t AFTER
   ```
2. Prefix before postfix. This has the advantage that actions in the prefix part are executed before actions in the postfix part. (But note that the right-recursiveness of `t` means that if its productions had actions, the actions would be executed right-to-left.)

   ```
   s: t
    | s AFTER
   t: AFTER
    | BEFORE t
   ```

   A completely left-recursive implementation of this alternative:

   ```
   s: t AFTER
    | s AFTER
   t: %empty
    | t BEFORE
   ```

Comment: After test the program a few times, it still has some error: when I start from free text, then I can't use properly the parentheses, and viceversa..

Comment: @gello: since i don't know what change you made exactly, it's very hard to give advice.

Comment: In the code i changed only:
{ s: t
 | SKIP { System.out.println("txt: "+$1); } s
t: exps
 | t exps }

Comment: What do you mean by "use properly"? In other words, what exactly is the problem? Does it not accept the input?

Comment: For example: if I type free text without parentheses, everything is ok (print the text). If I type some letters inside the parentheses, it will gave me error on the closed parentheses (it still print the text, but then it gave me error).

Comment: @Gello: That's how your original grammar was written. Look at the two instances of `SKIP`, and observe that one must be preceded by something and the other one must be followed by something. The consequence is that `SKIP` can never appear by itself. So `(foo)` is a syntax error; it requires `s` to derive `SKIP` and that is not possible.

Comment: @Gello: If that was not your intent, why didn't you go with the much simpler grammar `exp: parens | SKIP; s: exp | s exp;`? That's an arbitrary non-empty list of SKIPs and parenthesized things.